# sending messages to objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, messaging

I am trying to send a message with multiple objects but just cannot get it to work. It works perfectly using one message (objectsArray) but not both.

PlayerData.h:

```
- (void)savePlayerData:(NSArray *)objectsArray andKey:(NSString *)keyString;
```

PlayerData.m:

```
- (void)savePlayerData:(NSArray *)objectsArray andkey:(NSString *)keyString {
```

The following is where i try to call PlayerData from another .m:

```
    NSString *keyString = [[NSString alloc] init];  
    keyString = @"key test";
    PlayerData *accessPlayerDataFunction = [PlayerData new];
    [accessPlayerDataFunction savePlayerData:objs andKey:keyString];
```

objs is the NSArray.

The error i get is:

> warning: incomplete implementation of class 'PlayerData'
>   warning: method definition for '-savePlayerData:andKey:' not found

Comment: Note you can format lines as code by indenting them four spaces. The "101\n010" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a typo in your selector name within the implementation (the ".m" file).

in the header you write *andKey* (camel case)

```
(void)savePlayerData:(NSArray *)objectsArray andKey:(NSString *)keyString;
```

and in the implementation you have *andkey* (no camel case)

```
(void)savePlayerData:(NSArray *)objectsArray andkey:(NSString *)keyString
```

Apart from that you leak memory:

```
NSString *keyString = [[NSString alloc] init];
keyString = @"key test";
```

By assigning @"key test" to your variable, you loose reference to the original object you allocated the line before. You  can just assign @"key test" to keyString.

Comment: the leak with keyString i new and uses it only for testing.

Comment: the camel case explanation i am afraid i do not understand. isn't andKey a camel case? I would really appreciate if you could explain the answer a little bit more.

Comment: yes andKey is camel case. You use camel case in the .h file and no camel case in the .m file. That's why the compiler can't find the implementation. Like C, Objective-C is case-sensitive.

Comment: ahhhh i am totally blind. Now is see the problem. I have been looking on this for such a long time and did see it. I am stupid :-)

Comment: Such things happen if you stare at a problem for too long :)